# Unable to get output on Browser - .NET Core 3.1 Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1

I am running a Web API on Visual Studio 2019 - .Net Core 3.1 application where I am trying to display data from database SQL Server. I am not getting any errors or warnings, yet when I run it I get output on browser:

> This Site Can't be Loaded. The connection was reset.

Other times, I get message:"Unable to connect to IIS Web Server"

I have added the packages Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore,Core.Design,Core,Tools & Core.SQLServer. Am I missing any packages that I must add? This problem is with the connection to browser right?

[This is a screenshot of my debug page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA6YM.png)

Comment: Can you update your question and add more info like the question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604325/asp-net-core-3-1-app-on-iis-express-this-site-cant-be-reached

Comment: Done. Can you kindly help me @AndyRefuerzo